# Me, myself, or I? Which should I use?

Tags: grammatical-person, pronouns

In sentences such as the following, which is the proper pronoun to use and why?

> All crew members other than **me/myself/I** should evacuate immediately.

Which pronoun is the appropriate one when it appears in an exception for what people should do in the way this sentence is written?

Comment: I vote to keep this question open as the answer depends on a writing specific consideration (voice of the narrator) and is not merely a grammatical question. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Preliminary considerations

The grammatical rules are:

1. You can only use *myself* if you have already used *I* before in the same sentence:

   > I will do this myself.
2. You use *I* when you are the (grammatical) subject of the sentence:

   > I will do this.
3. You use *me* when you are the (grammatical) object of the sentence:

   > He will do this to me.

In your case you are part of the subject of the sentence, which is *all crew members other than I*. Therefore *I* would be grammatically correct.

The basic structure of your subject is `X * Y`, where `*` is a boolean operator. The same meaning as in your example can be expressed with *all crew members and not I*. Grammatically this is the same as *someone and I* or *someone or I* etc. The kind of logical relation between the two elements of the subject – and, or, and not – is grammatically irrelevant. The grammatically correct way to refer to yourself in a phrase such as `X and Y` is *I*.

And in fact this is what most speakers use with *and* and *or*, as Google Ngram Viewer shows:

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, usage seems to change for *not I* and *other than I*. Here *me* is replacing *I* in this phrase:

[image]

[image]

And indeed I get the impression that *and not I* and *other than I* are considered more formal and a bit old-fashioned by native speakers and that *and not me* and *other than me* would be what most native speakers would use in everyday speech today.

#### Recommendation

So it depends on the style of your narrative. Do you want to employ a more formal and correct language, for example for an omniscient narrator? Then use *I*. Or do you want to write in a language that has a more spoken feel? Then maybe use *me*.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence sounds like a command, presumably given by the ship's captain. In which case I don't think you want any pronoun as they wouldn't explicitly exclude themselves from their own command. It is after all their command, if they don't want to follow it then they don't have to.

Additionally this sounds like a command given in an emergency situation, in which case the shorter and simpler the command is the easier it will be for people to hear and understand it. The crew don't need to know that the captain isn't coming with them they just need to know that they need to leave, now.

They would just say 'All crew members should evacuate immediately.'

As an aside you could even exclude 'should', this would depend on the social setting the command is being given in. 'Should' makes this sound less like an order and more like a suggestion, which might be the polite way of ordering someone around in this setting.

If the context surrounding this command explains why they need to explicitly exclude themselves then I would use 'other than myself', but that's because I'm a native speaker of British English and that just sounds right to me. I can't speak to whether that's grammatically correct or not.

The only other situation that I can think of for this sentence is where the narrator is talking directly to the reader, in which case I would turn it into a subclause.

'All crew members, other than myself, should evacuate immediately.'

If that's the case however I think it needs a more conversational tone to sound natural.